# iPad: Make contact display like in mail app

Tags: ipad, email, contacts

What is the best way to create contacts view like in mail app? Is it available some native ios solutions?

[Look like this](http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/9162/screenshot20100923at125.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used

```
- (UIImage *)stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:(NSInteger)leftCapWidth topCapHeight:(NSInteger)topCapHeight
```

And UILabel on this image.

Works perfect